# AjaxFileUpload renders black button with event attached

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have spent the whole day on this so far. I am trying to use the FileUpload Control from the Ajax Control Toolkit. As soon as I add an EventHandler to the control:

```
OnClientUploadComplete="File_Upload"
```

It only renders a black button. I have looked through all questions here regarding this. I am using framwork 4.0 and double checked that I am using the 4.0 version of the toolkit. I referenced the toolkit in my Visual Studio project. This is my .aspx code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebUpload_de.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebFileTransfer.WebUpload_de" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="AjaxControlToolkit" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Default.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <title>File Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <AjaxControlToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" 
            runat="server">
        </AjaxControlToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
        <div>
            <AjaxControlToolkit:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1" 
                runat="server" OnClientUploadComplete="File_Upload"
                Width="500px" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

To my web.config I added this:

```
<system.web>
    <httpHandlers >
      <add verb="*" path="AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd" type="AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadHandler, AjaxControlToolkit"/>
    </httpHandlers>
</system.web>

<system.webServer>    
    <handlers>
      <add name="AjaxFileUploadHandler" verb="*" path="AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd" type="AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadHandler, AjaxControlToolkit"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

The code behind has the function defined:

```
protected void File_Upload(object sender, AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {
        string filename = e.FileName;
        string strDestPath = Server.MapPath("~/Documents/");
        AjaxFileUpload1.SaveAs(@strDestPath + filename);
    }
```

The control only renders when I remove the OnClientUploadComplete from the AjaxFileUpload tag.

Can anyone please explain?

Answer (score 0):

The `OnClientUploadComplete` is an client side event handler. And it must be bound to JavaScript function. Just add onto your page `script` element with this function:

```
function File_Upload(sender, args){
  alert("File uploaded");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Still I dont really get it. Aperently I can define a server side funtion to call with 'OnUploadComplete' or a client side function with 'OnClientUpload' complete. Both never seem to fire. Ever tutorial states just to implement the sever side funticon and be done with ist but that is simply not working! I changed to the OnClientUploadComplete and defined a javascript funtion with the alert message. The control is rendered now at least still the alert never fires!